# mysql function returns '??????' instead of correct string stored in table

Tags: mysql, function, charset

I have following situation:

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `City_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CityName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Nomer` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `city` (`City_ID`, `CityName`, `Nomer`) VALUES
(7, 'Берлин', NULL),
(2, 'Васюки', NULL),
(3, 'Челябинск', NULL),
(4, 'Магадан', NULL),
(5, 'Екатеринбург', NULL),
(209, 'Чебоксары', NULL),
(455, 'Санкт-Петербург', NULL),
(6, 'Москва', NULL),
(458, 'Sochi', NULL),
(8, 'Париж', NULL),
(9, 'Бонн', NULL),
(10, 'London', NULL);

drop function if exists WhatIsCityName;
delimiter $$

create function WhatIsCityName(id int)
returns varchar(20)
begin
select cityname into @cityname from city where city_id=id;
return @cityname;
END $$

delimiter ;
select WhatIsCityName(7);
```

Last select returns '??????' instead of 'Берлин', though
select WhatIsCityName(); returns correct value 'Moscow'

Comment: Encoding problem most likely.

Comment: *Last select returns '??????'* Do you use CLI? Does `--default-character-set=utf8` command line option is specified? https://dbfiddle.uk/PqpOtaUw Pay attention to the first codeblock which retrieves current session settings.

Comment: I have:
'''
character_set_client  utf8mb4
character_set_connection  utf8mb4
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results  utf8mb4
character_set_server  utf8mb4
character_set_system  utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\

collation_connection  utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server  utf8mb4_general_ci
'''
what is wrong with me?
I use phpMyAdmin

Comment: my text is in [link]https://dbfiddle.uk/jrMlHVa8 everything is all right, but in phpMyAdmin I receive '??????'. Something wrong with charset, but I don't understand what.

Comment: still waiting any comments